# Как избавиться от символов?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Есть две задачи:

- Удалить слова имеющие символы ‘&’ и ‘+’

  Пример:

  До: and he fell out into &-er the window .

  После: and he fell out into the window .
- Удалить слова имеющие префиксы '[' и ']' как суффикс, но оставить данные символы: [//], [/], и [*]

  Пример:

  До: and he's [/-] the jar smashes [//]
  smashed

  После: and he's the jar smashes [//] smashed

Нужно ли использовать регулярные выражения, или возможно решить с помощью срезов? Как это сделать?

Comment: Откуда взята задача?

Comment: Переведено.
Универская задача.

Answer (score 4):

Накидал пример, но его скорее всего нужно будет допиливать:

```
import re

text = "and he fell out into &-er the window. and he's [/-] the jar smashes [//] smashed"
print(text)

text = re.sub('\w*[&+]+-?\w*', '', text)

for match in re.findall(r'\[.+?\]', text):
    if match not in ('[//]', '[/]', '[*]'):
        text = text.replace(match, '')

print(text)
```

Консоль:

> and he fell out into &-er the window. and he's [/-] the jar smashes
> [//] smashed
>
> and he fell out into  the window. and he's  the jar smashes [//]
> smashed

Comment: Вы не тестировали производительность? Какая разница в скорости если пользоваться стандартным `replace` строк?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Нет :) если бы меня волновала производительность, писал бы на `с++` или переписал бы код на си и вызывал его в питоне )

Comment: я просто поинтересовался :)